# how to check the condition in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

```
   slitem    firstname    lastname
    1         aaa           bbb
```

Table 2

```
slitem    firstname    lastname
 1         null           null
 2          null        null
```

Result :

```
slitem    firstname    lastname
    1         aaa           bbb
    2        null          null
```

i want to join this two table....

help me

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.slitem, t2.slitem) AS slitem, 
       COALESCE(t1.firstname, t2.firstname) AS firstname, 
       COALESCE(t1.lastname, t2.lastname) AS lastname
FROM      table1 t1 
FULL JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.slitem = t2.slitem
```

(Edit because OMG Ponies edited my `FULL JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN`... which was not my intention!)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a left outer join:

SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON table2.slitem = Table1.slitem WHERE 1=1

Comment: where did you get left outer join from his criteria?  He wants the non-null value for each slitem if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You want a left join, just like the other answers said...but considering this is a rather basic thing to know when working SQL, you might want to read up a bit on it. [Here's a good place to start.](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Since `table1` has only 1 row, `table2` has 2 and the result has two, this would rather be a right join, or a full outer join as I posted.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I'm a noob too and missed that part, but the link is still good for a place for him to start reading :)